# Where should my application store large number of PDF files on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfilemanager

I am writing an iOS iPad app that will download several hundred large PDF files from the web and cache them on the iPad for offline use.

Where is the best place to store them on the iPad?  The local file system, core data, or some other place?  I am planning to use core data for an indexing and search mechanism (using thumbnail images etc), and will only access the PDF docs when a user specifically requests the full document.

Comment: this question might be better suited for http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Questions starting with "best X" usually get closed...

Comment: That's actually a legitimate question which could get your app rejected by Apple if not done properly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to do so is either the *Documents* directory or the *Cache* directory. Documents in the *Documents* directory are supposed to be *user-generated* content, so I believe this is not what you're looking for.

Instead, I think you should use the *Cache* directory, which you can access using this method :

```
- (NSString *)cacheDirectory {
{
    NSArray *pathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path    = [pathList objectAtIndex:0];
    return path;
}
```

Note that the *Cache* directory can be emptied by the system if you don't have enough space on the device. In my experience this almost never happens, but you might want to store your documents in a subdirectory of the *Library* directory other than *Cache* if you want to be absolutely, absolutely sure that the files never ever get deleted.

In this case, you *have to* set the `do not backup` flag on both the directory and the files, or else your app *will* be rejected.

See [the Apple guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/) (requires a developper account) for official information.

Comment: So a file that a user downloads is not considered "user generated"?

Comment: From @Nate_Hirsch: Sorry I don't have enough rep to comment or I would but I can edit....I believe that the cache directory will get cleared without warning by the os when memory starts running low so this would mean you would have to redownload everything. I think for permanent, or until specifically deleted storage, the documents directory is the way to go.

Comment: @MyNameIsTooCommon : I just added info on this, actually ;)
I believe that Apple frowns upon storing downloaded (but not user-generated) documents in the _Documents_ folder, although I'm not sure whether that will cause your app to be rejected.

Comment: @yms: No, I don't think so. "User generated" means "made by the user on the iPad". Also, the files in the _Documents_ directory are accessible through iTunes.

Comment: Very interesting point.  It is essential that the docs are available when the iPad is offline, so Documents seems the way to go but I don't want the app rejected.

Comment: @whatdoesitallmean: Which is why I also suggested using a subdirectory of _Library_. This is what we did with an app I worked on, and it was accepted fine. Like I said, you _have to_ set a particular flag to tell iCloud not to backup the data (not setting it caused our app to be rejected).

Comment: not setting the backup flag will cause app rejection even if my app doesn't use iCloud?

Comment: @laucel: It's been a while, so the answer might have changed since then, I haven't checked. IIRC you have to use that flag if you use a subdirectory of `Library` other than `Cache` and `Documents`. And your app does use iCloud in any case to backup user data -- which is everything in `Library` that doesn't have the _do not backup_ flag set.

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the content stored inside a subdirectory of Library directory never will be deleted by iOS? I believed that iOS can erase content inside this directory when the OS needs space in the same way that the Caches directory

Answer (score 1):

You should save them in the /documents folder. The purpouse for that folder is exactly that, store data that couldn't be redownloaded (or would be too big to do so). If it were temp data or data you could easily redownload, Apple suggests to use the /cache folder instead.

You can save the files with a specific name, and just save that name in CoreData to find them back.

Answer (score 1):

I would save the PDFs under the Documents folder. 
And create a core data sqlite datebase.
Create a core data entity with probably three attributes: thumbNail, localURL, and title.